# How do you get the maximum performance from Go while using interfaces?

Tags: go

I'm working on a simulator where every instruction counts. We were drawn to Go because of the interface abstraction, but from benchmarking, it is 5X worse to invoke the indirection of an interface rather than to call a method directly. However, our project structure now relies on the use of interfaces to get around circular dependencies. Is there a way to either make interfaces faster (doubtful) or get around circular dependencies without interfaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're seeing circular dependencies, that suggests you have your code in separate modules. Move all the code into a single module. Then you shouldn't require an interface. Modules are generally quite large groupings in Go. Don't create them just for code organization.

Comment: Hmmm... We had this originally, but it seems rather unorganized to keep every file in the project in one folder.  Currently we are already at 50+ files not counting test files.  Also parts of our project are logically independent. Is there a way to create subfolders while maintaining a single package?

Comment: No. Put them in one folder. Modules are not a code organization tool. They're a code reuse tool. It is completely normal to have many files in a single directory in Go. You may also be making your files too small. You do not need or desire a single file per type. What you're thinking of as being appropriate for directories may actually be appropriate for *files* in Go. Files are the natural code organization tool.

Comment: Alright I guess there is no way around it then.  Thanks!!

Comment: I would disagree about code organization part. Internal packages are very useful for code organization and pretty much everyone uses them for that. One big advantage - you don't polute your code with inner details. You have some specific component with internal state and variables. Without packages all of this will be accesible to everything else. That's just bad. To solve that you put it in a package and make public only what you actually want to be public. It rather looks like a bad practive not to use them just to get around the fact that interface calls are slow.

Comment: And if you're working on something where "every instruction counts" it should be obvious that Go is not the right choice. Most of the time it's due to GC but if even interface calls are a bottleneck then there is just no place for Go here.

Comment: @creker i'm not sure what you're talking about. 1. you can always write your hot code in C, C++ or in 1.7 fortrian and call it from cgo. 2. you can write in assembly. 3. there are a lot of ways to optimize around the gc. 4. go1.7 (current tip) optimizer got a LOT better. For example, my pure-go xxhash package is faster than the C version now using Go 1.7's optimizer.

Comment: @OneOfOne, cgo calls are very slow due to how they're implemented. Only if you can miminize jumping between C and Go. And that doesn't contradict with my post - Go is generally not suitable for raw performance and that's exactly why you mention cgo - to do something in a much faster language. You can optimize all you want but general consensus is that Go can't match C/C++ level of raw performance and probably never will due to presence of GC and the runtime. I understand it, golang team understands it. And the majority of benchmarks proof that. Go has it's place, C/C++ have their own

Comment: We are currently trying to get as much as we can out of go because GC is a big advantage for our project.  We have looked into cgo and writing in assembly, both of which are slow due to context switching too often, e.i. not enough time in C.  We wanted to look into Go for maintainability and it's strong typing.  We know that Go is not the best choice for performance, but it's other features were worth an exploration into how much performance we could get.

Comment: +1 for "Don't create them just for code organization". You end up writing much more code that way, and worrying about exported/unexported identifiers much more often too.

Comment: @sargas, how exactly you end up writing much more code? You write exactly like you would without packages. You need to worry only about exporting which is a good thing. Keeps your global scope clean and forces you to better design your components. That's how you achieve encapsulation which is always a good thing. Don't remember when throwing everything into the same scope become a good thing.

Comment: @creker I agree. Also, I'm not suggesting avoiding packages, but avoiding using packages for the sake of "code organization" only. If every little component is put under different packages you then have to start importing them everywhere they are needed and refer to the exported identifiers with `package.Identifier` rather then just `Identifier`. This is a little consequence of having many packages for the sake of "code organization".

Comment: @sargas, that doesn't sound like code organization. More like the lack of it. Code organization is about keeping relevant stuff in separate directories. You can look at `godoc` source - there're many internal packages just for code organization. Keeping it all in the same directory would be a mess. In go's case files no longer work well as code organization tool because there're no include statements - everything that's inside a directory is visible no matter how much files there is.

Comment: @creker Again, agreed.

Comment: @sirwillem, there is no context switching for calling functions that are written in assembly. Assembly functions cannot be inlined though (at least currently).

Comment: @kostya: Yes, You are right. I misspoke.  First I meant the switch between go and C and it is not a context switch because it is not switching between processes, but there is there is an overhead to switch between them.  For example we looked at using C to swap bytes when switching between little and big Endian.  This can be done with one function in C, but the cost of calling C to what amounted to one assembly was too high.

Comment: @sirwillem, I think you probably already know this, but I'll clarify just in case ;) It is possible to write Go functions in assembly without using cgo. There is no overhead of calling such function, but they won't be inlined (so there is always function call overhead).

Comment: @kostya Yes we did look into doing that and it is a good solution.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

Well, bad news first, interfaces are about as fast as they are gonna get for now, might be improved a bit by 1.7 but not much.

If your interfaces aren't massive, you can pass funcs around rather than interfaces.

Example:

```
func Sort(a sort.Interface) // can be rewritten as
func Sort(ln int, lessFn func(i, j) bool, swapFn func(i, j))
```

But I 100% agree with @RobNapier.

Comment: Thanks! This is great idea.  Especially if you make the functions their own type

Comment: Would it be really much faster? There is still indirection and these functions cannot be inlined.

Comment: @kostya well, depends, on go 1.6 (current release), it's ~25% faster, on current git though it's only ~2% faster. [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/II_DHdYaLQ)